Direct update of depending fields after selection in a SAP CAP application
I'm encountering an issue while trying to update a field that depends on the selection of a business partner (in this case, it's the customer field).
Currently, it seems that this field isn't recognized as dependent on the business partner during the selection process. However, after pressing save, the customer field gets updated accordingly.
I'm wondering if there's a way or an annotation I could use to update the customer field directly after selecting the business partner? If so, what would be the best approach?
I've replicated the problem in this GitHub repository for better understanding: https://github.com/floliver/cap-remoteentity
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!
